# SQL join not working (or very slow)

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have the following tables in mysql:

Table A:

```
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| sid   | varchar(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| type  | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Table B:

```
+---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field   | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| channel | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| sid     | varchar(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| type    | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

I want to find the rows from A that have an entry in B with the same sid. I tried the following Join command:

```
SELECT A.sid FROM A join B on A.sid=B.sid;
```

This query never gives me the answer. 
Tabe A has 465420 entries and table B has 291326 entries.

Why does it not work? 
Are there too many entries? 
Or does it have anything to do with the fact that I have no primary keys assigned?

Comment: If this query executed quickly, it would be a huge surprise. Please read up on primary keys

Comment: Give us an example, how field `sid` looks like.

Comment: 1468877429248867468571

Comment: Does `sid` field have duplicates in any of these tables?

Comment: Yes. One `sid` can have rows with different types.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your query is fine.  You would appear to need an index.  I would suggest `B(sid)`.

You can also write the query as:

```
select a.sid
from a
where exists (select 1 from b where a.sid = b.sid);
```

This will not affect performance -- unless there are lots of duplicates in `b` -- but it will eliminate issues caused by duplicates in `b`.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
    SELECT A1.sid 
    FROM (select A.sid from A order by sid) A1 
    join (select B.sid from B order by sid) B1 
    on A1.sid=B1.sid;
```

Else above holds true. You need index.